# download file via url python

Tags: python, django, file, download

I'm trying to download a file via an url. It is normally downloaded, but the problem is that , when I'm trying to open the file, it has 0 bytes.

Does anyone met this problem, or have idea from where can it come?

This is my code

```
def download():
    file_name = "/opt/static/avatar/20/mouse.png"
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path)
    return response
```

Comment: Please indicate the web framework you are using?

Comment: Have you tried setting `content_type` to `application/binary` ?

Comment: @Selcuk framework is Django

Comment: X-sendfile is a nonstandard header. What is your exact configuration (app server, web server, Django version)?

Comment: what is your webserver ? nginx, apache or something else ?

Comment: app server -  Microsoft Azure, web server - wsgi, nginx, Django - 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NginX does not support `X-Sendfile` header. You must use [`X-Accel-Redirect`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) instead:

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = smart_str(path)
```